# Adapt an Apache mod_rewrite RewriteRule not to act on physical directories

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have this RewriteRule that works too well :-)

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /script.html?id=$1 [L]
```

The bad thing about this rule is that it also matches physical directories which I don't want.

How can I tell the `mod_rewrite` to ignore physical directories and apply the above rule only when the directory matched does not exist?

Comment: Thank you everyone for all your fast and accurate answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). Put the following before your rule to exempt out directories and files

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great!!!

Thanks for all the answers, and thanks Joel for creating this great Site :)

Comment: Jeff Atwood et al. did the site. Joel is only his sidekick ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /script.html?id=$1 [L]
```